# Upload files using bottle and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, file, bottle

In my form I can select multiple file. I have to store theses files in database but they are pretty huge (1 Mo each ). So I would like to use a Thread to be able to use my application during the process . I don't want to create multiple thread, one for each file, because my fonction (StoreInBase) sort data in each file (with multiple thread my data aren't sorted in the database)

I've already created the Thread, the problem seems to come from bottle

```py
    class File(Thread):
        def __init__(self,files):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.files=files

        def run(self):
            for file in self.files:
                file.save("./save_file")
                OPO = data.Data("./save_file/"+file.filename)
                OPO.StoreInBase()

    @route('/',method='POST') 
    def file():
        files = request.files.getall('file')
        save_path="./save_file"
        if not path.exists(save_path):
        os.mkdir(save_path)
        thread_1=File(files)
        thread_1.start()
        redirect('/')
        thread_1.join()
        return 'Files stored in database !'
```

It's seem a file isn't closed. I've tried to replace

```py
    file.save("./save_file")
```

by

```py
    with open(file,'wb') as open_file:
        open_file.write(file.file.read())
```

but that didn't work

here is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\corma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\corma\Documents\infos\python\IAPP\app.py", line 24, in run
    file.save("./save_file")
  File "C:\Users\corma\Documents\infos\python\env\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 2406, in save
    self._copy_file(fp, chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\corma\Documents\infos\python\env\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 2384, in _copy_file
    read, write, offset = self.file.read, fp.write, self.file.tell()
  File "C:\Users\corma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 481, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

EDIT : ok now I have an operating code I've just made some changes

```py
class File(Thread):
    def __init__(self,files):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.files=files

    def run(self):
            OPO = data.Data("./save_file/"+self.files.filename)
            OPO.StoreInBase()


@route('/',method='POST') 
def file():
    files = request.files.getall('file')
    save_path="./save_file"
    if not path.exists(save_path):
        os.mkdir(save_path)
    for file in files:
        file.save("./save_file")
        thread_1=File(file)
        thread_1.start()
    redirect('/')
    thread_1.join()
```

But I still have a problem because data from my files are stored in a messy way. If you have a solution so that the Thread store data for one file then close the file and open the second.... and not all the same time

Comment: error shows that file is closed so you have to open it before you try to save it.

Comment: first try it without `Thread`. Maybe system can't send opened files to thread. Maybe you will have to open files again in thread.

Comment: It works fine without thread but that not the behaviour i'm expecting to.

Comment: I also test to send files one by one (with the code above )and it work fine. I believe there is something wrong with the for. System read the first one but maybe didn't open up the file after

Comment: I created working code but without storing in database and it works correctly. Maybe in `StoreInBase()` you close files.

Comment: Assuming you want to continue using the site while uploading, and if you have an appropriate HTML / JS front end, what about making an AJAX POST request to save the data asynchronously? I use this on my small web app.